# Calling a Stored Procedure from Java - Exception not thrown on ORA error

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, try-catch

I'm calling an Oracle Stored Procedure from Java, and have no problem sending input parameter values and getting the output parameter values back to Java once I execute the `CallableStatement`.

However, when i send some bad data into the Stored Procedure (to force an error) and execute the `CallableStatement`'s `execute` method, I'd expect a `SQLException` to be thrown in my method. This doesn't happen, and the code continues as normal.

When I run the Stored Procedure through SQL Developer, i can clearly see an oracle error message (code `ORA-06502`) displayed in the Log window. So it's a mystery to me why my Java code isn't catching any error message.

Does anyone have an idea what the source of this behaviour is? Is the Stored Procedure not throwing the error correctly; is the Java `try/catch` not recognizing the exception thrown? Unfortunately i have no access to the Stored Proc code to check how they're handling errors.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe a SQLException is thrown uness the stored proc is coded to explicitly do so.  https://community.oracle.com/thread/129500?start=0&tstart=0.  There's no doubt that the JVM will catch it if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Show us the code of the procedure and the java code that call the procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't throw SQLException because the call stored procedure Java function (CallableStatement) has successfully sent the command to Oracle. If this procedure is executed with success, the methode of CallableStatement give us 0, otherwise different of 0, so you don't see SQLException.

But in case of SQLDevelopper, It's a true interpreter SQL for Oracle, so you can see the SQLException.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is thrown only when your first executable statement fails in stored procedure. If at lest one statement executes correctly except the first one exception won't be thrown.

You can try putting transaction in stored procedure itself and catch exception if any statement fails and throw an exception from catch block. All of this in stored procedure.